# Need assistance with these probability questions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A. From a group of 9 couples, at random 8 persons are chosen. What is the probability that between the 8 chosen there are exacly 2 couples?

---

B. At random (without returns)
 3 numbers are chosen from the set $\{1,2... 3n\}$. What is the probability that the sum of the three chosen numbers is divisible by  3?

---

C. 5 dice are thrown, and the ones that show a "two" are put to the side, thereafter another throw takes place, of the remaining dice and the total number of "twos" are recorded (over both throws). What is the probability that the number of fallen "twos" in the second throw is larger that the first, if it's known that the total number of fallen "twos" is $4$
?

For A. Thought $$\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{4}\binom{2}{1}^4\over \binom{18}{8}$$ Because of the nine couple one can be chosen in 9 over 1 ways and from the remaining 8 couples 6 persons that are not a couple need to be chosen.
For B. (from the hint in the answer):$${4}\over{27}$$ beacause im narrowing down the chosen numbers in respect to its modularity to 3, which is relevant in hint

For C. I would just find the area in the domain of $[0,5]\times[0,5]$ of the set given in hint. The answer provided i cannot comprehend but suffices i have no doubt.

Comment: Where do you need help?  What have you tried to do?

Comment: I do not have time right know to post my efforts, i will do so tomorrow morning, thanks for the interest, (how would i represent a number as undivisable by 3 in workable terms (this is related to a seperate question, similar to B here?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A. From a group of 9 couples, at random 8 persons are chosen. What is the probability that between the 8 chosen there are exacly 2 couples?

Hint: How many ways are there to choose 2 couples and 4 people each from 4 of the 7 remaining couples.

> B. At random (without returns) 3 numbers are chosen from the set {1,2...3n} . What is the probability that the sum of the three chosen numbers is divisible by 3?

*Hint 1:* in order for the sum of three numbers to be divisible by 3 they have to be of one of these forms (where $a,b,c$ are some integers):

- $3a, 3b+1, 3c+2$
- $3a, 3b, 3c$
- $3a+1, 3b+1, 3c+1$
- $3a+2, 3b+2, 3c+2$

What is the probability of each of these *disjoint* cases?

*Hint 2:* Partition the set.

> C. 5 dice are thrown, and the ones that show a "two" are put to the side, thereafter another throw takes place, of the remaining dice and the total number of "twos" are recorded (over both throws). What is the probability that the number of fallen "twos" in the second throw is larger that the first, if it's known that the total number of fallen "twos" is 4  ?

Let $A$ be the number of twos in the roll of 5 dice.  Let $B$ be the number of two in the roll of $5-A$ dice.   Calculate $P(B>A \mid A+B=4)$

Hint: $P(A=x) = \binom{5}{x} 5^{5-x}/6^5
\\ P(B=y \mid A=x) = \binom{x}{y} 5^{x-y}/6^x
\\ P(B=y, A=n-y) = \binom{5}{n-y}\binom{n-y}{y} 5^{5-y}/6^{5+n-y}
\\ P(A+B=n) = \sum_{y=0}^n P(B=y, A=n-y)
\\ P(B> A\cap A+B=n) = \sum_{y=n/2+1}^n P(B=y, A=n-y)
$

---

> For A. Thought
>   $$\frac{\binom{9}{1}\binom{2}{1}^6\binom{8}{6}}{\binom{18}{8}}$$
>   Because of the nine couple one can be chosen in 9 over 1 ways and from the remaining 8 couples 6 persons that are not a couple need to be chosen.

Save that you originally asked the probability of selecting exactly $2$ couples, your reasoning is correct.

> For B. (from the hint in the answer):
>   $$\frac 4{27}$$
>   beacause im narrowing down the chosen numbers in respect to its modularity to 3, which is relevant in hint

I ... have no idea how you got that from the hint, but the answer is a fraction involving functions of $n$ in both the denominator and numerator.

> For C. I would just find the area in the domain of [0,5]×[0,5] of the set given in hint. The answer provided i cannot comprehend but suffices i have no doubt.

You simply need to calculate $P(B>A \mid A+B=4)$, given that the random variable $A$ (the count of twos in the first roll) has a binomial distribution, and that the variable $B$ (count of twos in the second roll) conditioned over $A$ has a binomial distribution.
$$\begin{align}
A &\sim \mathcal{Bin}(5, 1/6)
\\
 B\mid A=x &\sim \mathcal{Bin}(5-x,1/6)
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(A>B\mid A+B=4) &= \frac{\mathsf P(B>A, A+B=4)}{\mathsf P(A+B=4)}
\\ &= \frac{\sum_{x=0}^1 \mathsf P(A=x)\mathsf P(B=4-x)}{\sum_{x=0}^4 \mathsf P(A=x)\mathsf P(B=4-x)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: When you get the chance , could you comment on my thoughts in the question, not sure if my first two are correct?

Comment: For B i thought to look at the numbers chosen in respect to their remainder to being divided by 3 {0,1,2}. 3 are chosen so $3^3$ in the denominator and 4 combinations are favorable as the numbered above.

Comment: We haven't studied random variables yet, that is next week.